# Login into skype for business using UCMA with autodiscovery

Tags: skype-for-business, ucma, autodiscovery

Is it possible to login into skype for business 2016 using UCMA 5.0 with autodiscovery setting on target server?
The config from code sample requires FQDN of skype server, but all I know about server is autodiscovery and a part of domain name (like user@domain.com).
It cannot connect to server and returns TLS exception with certificate information inside inner exception (I will provide code of exception later).
I used FQDN of this pattern: https://sip.domain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what type of UCMA application you are talking about.

There are two types of UCMA applications:

- [Client Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn466052(v=office.16).aspx)
- [Server Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn466051(v=office.16).aspx)

The Server Platform requires to be pre-setup for a application pool / FE Pool (the FQDN you talked about in your question).  This allows you to create [ApplicationEndpoints and UserEndpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn466053(v=office.16).aspx) without any user credentials but the UCMA application must be run on the application pool computer and is confirmed with certificates.

The Client Platform can be run from any machine and can only use "UserEndpoint"'s.  The UserEndpoint requires only the sip uri, username and password.  There is no need for the server pool FQDN.  In this mode, the UCMA application will use autodiscover just like any SfB "client" (e.g. lync.exe).